# Databricks Jobs - Is there a way to restart a failed task instead of the whole pipeline?

Tags: databricks, databricks-workflows

If I have for example a (multitask) Databricks job with 3 tasks in series and the second one fails - is there a way to start from the second task instead of running the whole pipeline again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Right now* this is not possible, but if you refer to the [Databrick's Q3 (2021) public roadmap](https://databricks.com/p/webinar/databricks-q3-product-roadmap-webinar), there were some items around improving multi-task jobs.

Update: September 2022. This functionality was released back in May 2022nd with name [repair & rerun](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/05/06/save-time-and-money-on-data-and-ml-workflows-with-repair-and-rerun.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Databricks on Azure it is possible via Azure Data Factory.

Comment: The intent was to steer away from ADF, but thanks nonetheless. :)